# Unable to understand dimension mismatch error in Julia

Tags: julia, runtime-error, dimensions, flux.jl

I’m a beginner with Julia and ML. I’m attempting to re-use code from the Flux Model Zoo, specifically [this](https://github.com/FluxML/model-zoo/tree/master/vision/mlp_mnist), to classify images from [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mloey1/ahcd1). Below is my version of the code - I modified the data load and the params in the build_model to account for the difference in image size and the number of character types to be classified. The original had 28x28 and 10 digits, the arabic character set had 32x32 images and 28 characters.

```
function getimages(filename)
    filepath = pwd() * "/images/" * filename

    mtrx = Matrix(DataFrame(CSV.File(filepath)))
    r, _ = size(mtrx)

    v = Vector{Matrix{Int64}}()

    for i = 1:r
        push!(v, reshape(m[i, :], 32, 32))
    end

    v
end

function getlabels(filename)
    filepath = pwd() * "/images/" * filename
    vec(Matrix(DataFrame(CSV.File(filepath))))
end

function load_data(args)
    train_data_file = "csvTrainImages.csv"
    test_data_file = "csvTestImages.csv"
    train_label_file = "csvTrainLabel.csv"
    test_label_file = "csvTestLabel.csv"

    train_data = getimages(train_data_file)
    test_data = getimages(test_data_file)
    train_labels = getlabels(train_label_file)
    test_labels = getlabels(test_label_file)

    xtrain = Flux.flatten(train_data)
    xtest = Flux.flatten(test_data)

    ytrain, ytest = onehotbatch(train_labels, 1:28), onehotbatch(test_labels, 1:28)

    train_loader = DataLoader((xtrain, ytrain), batchsize=args.batchsize, shuffle=true)
    test_loader = DataLoader((xtest, ytest), batchsize=args.batchsize)

    return train_loader, test_loader
end

function build_model(; imgsize=(32,32,1), nclasses=28)
    return Chain(
            Dense(prod(imgsize), 32, relu),
            Dense(32, nclasses))
end

function loss_and_accuracy(data_loader, model, device)
    acc = 0
    ls = 0.0f0
    num = 0
    for (x, y) in data_loader
        x, y = device(x), device(y)
        ŷ = model(x)
        ls += logitcrossentropy(model(x), y, agg=sum)
        acc += sum(onecold(cpu(model(x))) .== onecold(cpu(y)))
        num +=  size(x, 2)
    end
    return ls / num, acc / num
end

@kwdef mutable struct Args
    η::Float64 = 3e-4       # learning rate
    batchsize::Int = 256    # batch size
    epochs::Int = 10        # number of epochs
    use_cuda::Bool = true   # use gpu (if cuda available)
end

function train(; kws...)
    args = Args(; kws...) # collect options in a struct for convenience

    if CUDA.functional() && args.use_cuda
        @info "Training on CUDA GPU"
        CUDA.allowscalar(false)
        device = gpu
    else
        @info "Training on CPU"
        device = cpu
    end

    # Create test and train dataloaders
    train_loader, test_loader = load_data(args)

    # Construct model
    model = build_model() |> device
    ps = Flux.params(model) # model's trainable parameters

    ## Optimizer
    opt = ADAM(args.η)

    ## Training
    for epoch in 1:args.epochs
        for (x, y) in train_loader
            x, y = device(x), device(y) # transfer data to device
            gs = gradient(() -> logitcrossentropy(model(x), y), ps) # compute gradient
            Flux.Optimise.update!(opt, ps, gs) # update parameters
        end
    
        # Report on train and test
        train_loss, train_acc = loss_and_accuracy(train_loader, model, device)
        test_loss, test_acc = loss_and_accuracy(test_loader, model, device)
        println("Epoch=$epoch")
        println("  train_loss = $train_loss, train_accuracy = $train_acc")
        println("  test_loss = $test_loss, test_accuracy = $test_acc")
    end
end
```

I get the following error when I train the model. Specifically, during the gradient computation. Could you help me understand which two matrices the error refers to and point me towards a solution? My guess is that it has to do with the build_model params, but I’m not quite sure what needs to change and how.

```
DimensionMismatch("matrix A has dimensions (32,1024), matrix B has dimensions (1,256)")
macro expansion@interface2.jl:0[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::typeof(throw), ::DimensionMismatch)@interface2.jl:9
_pullback@matmul.jl:814[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::typeof(LinearAlgebra._generic_matmatmul!), ::Matrix{Matrix{Float32}}, ::Char, ::Char, ::Matrix{Float32}, ::Matrix{Matrix{Int64}}, ::LinearAlgebra.MulAddMul{true, true, Bool, Bool})@interface2.jl:0
_pullback@matmul.jl:802[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::typeof(LinearAlgebra.generic_matmatmul!), ::Matrix{Matrix{Float32}}, ::Char, ::Char, ::Matrix{Float32}, ::Matrix{Matrix{Int64}}, ::LinearAlgebra.MulAddMul{true, true, Bool, Bool})@interface2.jl:0
_pullback@matmul.jl:302[inlined]
_pullback@matmul.jl:275[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::typeof(LinearAlgebra.mul!), ::Matrix{Matrix{Float32}}, ::Matrix{Float32}, ::Matrix{Matrix{Int64}})@interface2.jl:0
_pullback@matmul.jl:153[inlined]
_pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::typeof(*), ::Matrix{Float32}, ::Matrix{Matrix{Int64}})@interface2.jl:0
_pullback@basic.jl:147[inlined] ....
```

Comment: Note that this error will be hopefully getting better soon https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/40118#issuecomment-865068949

Answer (score 0):

Solved by fixing the get images method as below.

```
function getimages(filename)
    filepath = pwd() * "/images/" * filename

    mtrx = Matrix(DataFrame(CSV.File(filepath)))

    return mtrx'
end
```

Comment: Since this solves the problem, could you please mark it as the answer so that it doesn't show up as an Unanswered question?